# limit spatial extent of arcpy cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

How do I limit spatial extent of features that is returned by arcpy.da.SearchCursor?  Can I use arcpy.env.extent?  Or somehow come up with sql statement to specify spatial relationship?   Or do I have to arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management to do intersection of my area of interest.

EDIT:
Here is what I want to accomplish.  Want to visit features from a feature class within a set extent.  I was hoping that second use of arcpy.da.SearchCursor respects arcpy.env.extent, but apparently it ignores it.

How can I do this (visit spatial subset of features)?  I want to have method with decent efficiency (e.g. avoid copying of features).

```
import arcpy
def proc():

    # I/O files
    fo = open('c:/users/yosuke/documents/log.txt','w')
    fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('c:/Users/Yosuke/documents/ArcGIS/polytical_boundaries.mdb/tl_2010_us_state10', r'in_memory\fc')

    # grab everything, works fine
    arcpy.env.extent = 'MAXOF'
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
    m = len(list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ('SHAPE@',))))
    extent = arcpy.Describe(fc).extent
    # got 52 from both, as expected
    fo.write('n: %s\n' % n)
    fo.write('m: %s\n' % m)
    fo.write('extent: %s\n' % extent)
    fo.write('\n')

    # want to grab only western USA
    arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(-120, 0, -90, 80)
    # this counts 27 western states, I suppose.
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
    # this still marches through all states, I want this to be spatial subset of USA
    m = len(list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ('SHAPE@',)))) 
    extent = arcpy.Describe(fc).extent
    fo.write('n: %s\n' % n)
    fo.write('m: %s\n' % m)
    fo.write('extent: %s\n' % extent)
    fo.write('\n')

    # For now I am making copy of feature class
    # turned out that this is not very bad for my application, other processing
    # tasks I am applying on cursor rows are more computationally expensive.
    # I still want to know if this is standard way to accomplish this kind of
    # tasks (subset cursor by extent)
    fc2 = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r'in_memory\fc', r'in_memory\fc2')
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc2).getOutput(0))
    m = len(list(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, ('SHAPE@',))))
    extent = arcpy.Describe(fc2).extent
    fo.write('n: %s\n' % n)
    fo.write('m: %s\n' % m)
    fo.write('extent: %s\n' % extent)
    fo.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I have tested the extent does not limit the search cursors spatially..When using tools like "GetCount_Management" etc. it is limited but it appears that Cursors do not follow the extent

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out so I may be incorrect but I think the search cursor will honor the env.extent based on these notes in ArcGIS help.

[Output Extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004s000000)

> extent (Read and Write)
>
> Tools that honor the Output Extent environment will only process
>   features or rasters that fall within the extent specified in this
>   setting.

[Cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)

> Note:   Cursors honor layer/table view definition queries and
>   selections. The cursor object only contains the rows that would be
>   used by any geoprocessing tool during an operation.

I'm taking that last sentence to mean if a geoprocessing tool will only process features that fall into the defined extent than cursors will have the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I also thought that arcpy.env.extent does what I wanted, but I am not sure about the behavior of my script.  I should simply say "arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(a,b,c,d)" then "for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,['SHAPE@',]):" should let me iterate he geometry, correct?  I try post my code see why it's not behaving what I exptect